# No se puede insertar datos null en la tabla

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de crear un cursor y al momento de realizar el insert correspondiente me sale error no se puede ingresar datos de tipo null en la columna subtotal de la tabla boleta.

les adjunto mi código para ver si pueden ayudarme, el error me aparece en la línea, espero puedan ayudarme y me ayuden a encontrar mi error.

```sql
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Calcular_Descuento]
    @num_boleta varchar (8)
    AS
    DECLARE @total numeric (10,2), @subtotal numeric (10,2) , @descuento numeric (10,2) = 0, @num_op varchar (8), @fechaop datetime, @efectivo varchar (8), @tarjeta varchar (8), @ctp varchar (8)
    
    DECLARE Subtotal_Descuento CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  op.num_OrdenP , op.fecha_OrdenP, OP.num_OrdenP, OP.total, OP.cod_TipoPago
        FROM  ORDEN_PEDIDO OP WHERE OP.num_OrdenP = OP.num_OrdenP
    OPEN Subtotal_Descuento
    FETCH Subtotal_Descuento INTO @num_op ,@fechaop, @num_op, @total, @ctp
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN 
            PRINT @num_op
            SET @efectivo = 1 
            SET @tarjeta = 2
    --insertar cabecera, linea 17
         INSERT BOLETA (num_Boleta, fecha_Boleta, num_OrdenP, subtotal, descuento, total  )
         VALUES ( @num_op ,@fechaop, @num_op,  @subtotal , @descuento, @total)
            SET @num_boleta= @@IDENTITY
            IF @ctp = @efectivo
            BEGIN
                --Guardamos Subtotal
                SET @subtotal = @total 
                --Calculamos el descuento
                SET @descuento = @total * 0.10
                --Insertamos los datos
                SET @total = @subtotal - @descuento
                    INSERT INTO BOLETA (subtotal, descuento, total  )
                     VALUES (  @subtotal, @descuento, @total)
            END
    
            IF @ctp = @tarjeta
                BEGIN
                    --Guardamos Subtotal
                    SET @subtotal = @total 
                    --Calculamos Descuento
                    SET @descuento = @total * 0.05
                    SET @total = @subtotal - @descuento
                        INSERT INTO BOLETA (subtotal, descuento, total  )
                        VALUES (  @subtotal, @descuento, @total)
                
            END
            UPDATE BOLETA SET subtotal = @subtotal WHERE num_Boleta = @num_op
            UPDATE BOLETA SET descuento = @descuento WHERE num_Boleta = @num_op
    
            FETCH Subtotal_Descuento INTO @num_op ,@fechaop, @num_op, @total, @ctp
        END
    CLOSE Subtotal_Descuento
    DEALLOCATE Subtotal_Descuento
```

Comment: Debe  estar configurada  la columna  subtotal en la  tabla boleta como  no aceptar valores nulos. Si  quieres  que  acepte nulos tendras que  cambiar  la definición  de la 
 columna  en la tabla. En todo caso insertale 0.

Comment: Tambien podrias utiliazr Utiliza  COALESCE(@subtotal,0) que devuelve el primer no nulo..

Comment: El procedure que muestras tiene muchos problemas, además del que mencionas. Por ejemplo, estás filtrando todas las filas de la tabla OrdenPedido. Además de no ser nada práctico el uso de este tipo de bucles en SQL. Porque no cambias la pregunta con un escenario donde indicas, lo que tienes, y lo que deseas obtener, para que la ayuda que te presten te sirva de algo y sea la adecuada. [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)